# Type mismatch : cannot convert from double[][] to double[]

Tags: java, arrays

I'm very new to Java and this issue just came up, I tried searching but could not find out as to why this is happening.

```
public class Cliente{

    private int clientID;
    private String clientName;
    private double clientDebt;
    private double[][] clientHistory;


    public void registerID(int newID) {
        this.clientID = newID;
    }

    // Here is the issue
    public void newInvoice(double[][] invoice) {
        this.clientHistory[this.clientHistory.length] = invoice;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to keep track of a list of invoices with a changing number of invoices? If so, you may want to use an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). This class allows you to add new invoices without removing the old ones. Your class would look like this:

```
public class Cliente{

    private int clientID;
    private String clientName;
    private double clientDebt;
    private ArrayList<double[]> clientHistory = new ArrayList<double[]>();


    public void registerID(int newID) {
        this.clientID = newID;
    }

    // Here is the issue
    public void newInvoice(double[] invoice) {
        clientHistory.add(invoice);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong :P Just assign

```
this.clientHistory = invoice;
```

your `double[][]` is a matrix, it is an array of arrays, you are trying to put a matrix into an array of index `this.clientHistory.length`

Comment: assigning it automatically adds a new line to the matrix array? basically i want to achieve this format :      {Date, Total price, Status} on each line of the clientHistory

Comment: No, it replaces the matrix with new one. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Should clientHistory be an array of invoices? In such case replace double[][] array with a List<double[][]> and use lists add method. (listName.add(invoice))

Comment: If you want to have a Date, Total price and Status, I'd suggest creating a class with such fields and then creating a List of instances of such objects.

Comment: I wanted to put them in the same array to iterate trough the Invoices by date and generate sorted lists